# How to get Subject of annotation in pdf using itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, itext

How to get subject [image]

I can get author using

```
PdfString Author = annot.GetAsString(PdfName.T);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read this topic before ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please try to [edit] your question and try to explain more detail and perhaps add better code example.

Comment: It is common to accept (and upvote) the answer if it solves your problem. If it is helpful you would only upvote and comment about the remaining issue(s)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.
You can get the subject quite similar as the author:

`PdfString subject = annot.GetAsString(PdfName.SUBJ);`

If PdfName.SUBJ is not (yet) available use

`PdfString subject = annot.GetAsString(new PdfName("Subj"));`